# Hot to show progress bar for inter server file transfer

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload, progress-bar, file-transfer

I am developing an php application where I can upload a compressed file.

Once the compressed file gets upload, it should be uncompressed and individually all these file should be transferred to another server using rest web service.

But as this functionality happens in background, I also want to show the progress bar in browser like 30% of 2nd file is transferred.

Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using: 
 flush();
 ob_flush();

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
 echo "SOME TEXT HERE"
 flush()
 ob_flush()
 
}